# So I tried creating a checklist with points in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm still currently trying to create a checklist with points as a reference if you are unsure you have COVID-19. ex. "if you have 1 point then you are still fine"

Right now all checkboxes work except for one which is the second checkbox

```
    Public Class Form1

    Dim pts As Byte
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = "You have " & pts
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

        If Me.CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            pts = pts + 1
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged

        If Me.CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            pts = pts + 1
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged

        If Me.CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            pts = pts + 98

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        CheckBox1.CheckState = 0
        CheckBox2.CheckState = 0
        CheckBox3.CheckState = 0
        Label1.Text = ""
        pts = 0

    End Sub
 End Class
```

I don't know what else I can do really

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Are you sure it's the second CheckBox that isn't working?  Because CheckBox3 is looking at CheckBox1 to add its points.  If you uncheck a box, you should be subtracting the value, too.

Comment: Also, every time a checkbox is changed it will add to the current total, so you can add as many points as you want by toggling a single checkbox on-and-off over and over.

Comment: Wait @LarsTech thank you I just noticed haha

Comment: But, how can I disable unlimited points? Via unchecking and checking again

Comment: As LarsTech said, you need to subtract the points again whenever the box is un-checked.

Comment: Since this is your first question it was flagged for review, allow me to give some pointers! It seems like you have discoved the answer to your question, and clarified the problem in the process, so please post this answer (it's perfectly fine to answer your own question) and edit the question to be clearer. Starting a question with "so i..." will make it difficult for others with the same problem to find your solution. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Ah right sorry I'll keep that in mind! Thanks for the welcome! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total values are just added but not subtracted on un-check event. Just simply use `Else` statement to do so. Look at the following example:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    If Me.CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        pts = pts + 1
    Else
        pts = pts - 1
    End If

End Sub
```